# What are the evidences that quantum simulation have a future?

Tags: resource-request, simulation

Here future means orders of improvement which can solve rather different problems e.g. emergent phenomenon.

For example, the first integrated logic only have several transistors, now it have billions of them, which is $10^9$ better thats a future.

If quantum simulation system can only scale from several bits to 1000 bits, it doesn't make big difference since you can only improve from hydrogen to benzene.

The goal is to simulate a whole cell or any small piece of material and predict its properties with high precision.

IMO there are several difference between the scalability of quantum simulation and CMOS logic:

1. It's not 1+1=2, there seems to be noises to overcome, and it's possible that the mothed to overcome noises cannot scale much at all.
2. The complexity is not linear too, but poylmonial like the bits required scale with $n^4$ ($n$ is the number of particles in the system). For CMOS circuits you get double performance with double gates (not considering interconnect bottleneck).

Could anybody provide link to an article discussing future possibilities of quantum systems simulation and possible bottlenecks?